# Entity Framework: Many-to-many relationship with self

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have this entity:

```
public abstract class DataField
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DataField> Referals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DataField> Encapsulated { get; set; }
}
```

And this map:

```
public class DataFieldMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<DataField>
{
    public DataFieldMapping()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Referals).WithMany(x => x.Encapsulated);
        HasMany(x => x.Encapsulated).WithMany(x => x.Referals);
        ToTable("DataField");
    }
}
```

The point is that a DataField can have many encapsulated DataFields and can itself be encapsulated/referred to by many other DataFields.

I am not sure if both HasMany lines are needed. But...

When I run my test that creates two DataFields, one referring to the other and the other being encapsulated by the first, I get this error:

Invalid object name 'dbo.DataFieldDataFields'.

I makes sense that it is necessary to store the many-to-many relationship in a separate table. So I guess things would work if I create a table called DataFieldDataFields with the right columns. But is there any way to tell EF that this table is called something else than DataFieldDataFields?

Edit: I now created that table, and it works. But EF expects the columns of that table to be named DataField_Id and DataField_Id1. So same issue: Is there a way to tell EF the names of these columns and the name of the table itself, if I want the columns and the table to be named something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be simple:

```
        HasMany(x => x.Referals).WithMany(x => x.Encapsulated).Map(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("DataFieldJoin");
                c.MapLeftKey("RefId");
                c.MapRightKey("EncapId");
            });
```